# Difference between file_get_contents and $ _POST

Tags: php

I'm sending data through POST from one application to another, using the file_get_contents function, I can't receive the data but using the variable $ _POST I can get it. Which would be the most suitable to receive the data?
I would like to send a token for authentication together, how could I do that?

```
$cont = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo gettype($cont);

NULL
```

And when I try the pre-defined variable, I can receive the data.

```
$cont = $_POST;
echo gettype($cont);

array
```

Comment: Depends entirely on the POST request payload / MIME type. Makes little difference in regards to a "token" being submitted.

Answer (score 3):

`file_get_contents('php://input')` gets the raw POST data as a string.

`$_POST` gets the POST data after PHP has automatically decoded it from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encodings.

If the data isn't encoded using one of those methods (e.g. if it is JSON as per your first example which uses `json_decode`) then `$_POST` won't be populated.